# Unable to extract text and images from specific PDF

Tags: ruby, pdf, command-line, ubuntu-14.04, pdfbox

Can anyone please let me know how I can extract all the text and images from a PDF. I am able to extract images in scenario like, which I created a PDF with few lines of text and 2 png images using Google Docs. But, I am unable to extract images from a sample [pdf](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jgl1l1ytsfjngnv/example.pdf?dl=0).

I have tried with the following:

In Ruby:

1) "pdf-reader" gem, it is supporting extraction of only few formats of images.

2) "docsplit" gem, it is only able to extract text and unable to extract images.

Command-line utility:

1) "pdfimages" tool, it is supporting extraction of only few formats of images.

Java library:

1) "pdfbox" library, it is supporting extraction of only few formats of images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## 1.

**Extracting text:**

```
pdftotext -layout the.pdf -
```

Extract all pages' text to `<stdout>`.

```
pdftotext -layout -nopgbrk the.pdf the-3-5.txt
```

Extract all pages' text to file `the.txt`, and don't insert these pesky **`^L`** characters signifying new pages.

```
pdftotext -f 3 -l 5 -layout the.pdf -
```

Extract pages' 3--5 text to the-3-5.txt.

## 2.

**Extracting images**

```
pdfimages -f 4 -l 7 -j the.pdf myprefix--
```

Extract all images from pages 4 through 7 as JPEGs (if possible!) and name them with the prefix `myprefix---`.

If extracting as JPEGs is not possible, the images will be extracted as pure raster `PPM` or `PGM`.

The latest versions of `pdfimages` (Poppler fork) lets you specify `-png` (and more) to get all images as PNGs.

Using the latest version of `pdfimages` gives you these options:

```
$ pdfimages -h

   pdfimages version 0.33.0
   Copyright 2005-2015 The Poppler Developers - http://poppler.freedesktop.org
   Copyright 1996-2011 Glyph & Cog, LLC
   Usage: pdfimages [options] <PDF-file> <image-root>
     -f <int>       : first page to convert
     -l <int>       : last page to convert
     -png           : change the default output format to PNG
     -tiff          : change the default output format to TIFF
     -j             : write JPEG images as JPEG files
     -jp2           : write JPEG2000 images as JP2 files
     -jbig2         : write JBIG2 images as JBIG2 files
     -ccitt         : write CCITT images as CCITT files
     -all           : equivalent to -png -tiff -j -jp2 -jbig2 -ccitt
     -list          : print list of images instead of saving
     -opw <string>  : owner password (for encrypted files)
     -upw <string>  : user password (for encrypted files)
     -p             : include page numbers in output file names
     -q             : don't print any messages or errors
     [....]
```

What more image formats do you want? If you need other formats use ImageMagick's `convert` command.

Also, there are no other "formats" embedded in PDFs.

Basically, the only compression methods for images embedded in PDFs are:

- JPEG (then `/DCTDEcode` filter is mentioned as uncompression hint to the PDF viewer),
- JBIG2 (`/JBIG2Encode`),
- Fax compression (`CCITTFaxDecode`) and
- JPEG2000 (`JPXDecode`).

All other images embedded in PDFs basically are pure raster data anyway (`PPM` or `PGM`), and their PDF-internal compression is one of the *other* standard compression methods available for general stream compression:

- `/FlateDecode` (ZIP/Deflate algorithm),
- `/LZWDecode` (Lempel-Ziv-Welch algorithm) and
- `/RunLengthDecode`.

---

### Update

I only now had time to look at your linked sample PDF, sorry.

As @mkl wrote in his comment, what *looks* like an image ***isn't*** always an image in PDF technical parlance. For example, on your PDF's page 7 there is the (famous) tiger head. This is completely composed from vector elements, which are placed inline into the page's `/Contents` stream. 
The same is true for the depicted chess board.

I believe the tiger image was designed with the help some vector graphics program a few decades ago (Adobe Illustator?) when it had freshly been released, and exported to EPS. A PDF viewer in may cases has now way to identify inline vector elements (which could be simple horizontal lines) from other contents. Unless these vector elements are "grouped" into an XObject (which `pdfimages` would no be able to extract either, but which would help with manual isolation and extraction...)

These vector elements cannot be automatically extracted by any (Free and Open Source Software, or gratis closed source software) tool I know.

A "real" image in PDF parlance is a rectangle of pixel data. These are the only type of images which can be extracted by a tool like `pdfimages`.

Comment: Thanks Kurt Pfeifle for detailed answer. I tried your suggestions but still I am not able to extract images from the PDF I am checking (attached in question). I really don't have idea on how PDF stores images. I would appreciate if you could provide some references to worth looking.

Comment: You talk about extracting images. Most people then assume you are talking about bitmap images. The images in your file are (at least partially) vector graphics.

Comment: @Kurt Pfeifle nicely explained. Would you please suggest any other opensource solution other than mentioned tools/utilities which are more powerful in a sense that can extract text and images close to the PDF content?

Comment: @AmitPatel: Sorry, I do not understand your question. I don't know what you mean by *"are more powerful in a sense that can extract text and images close to the PDF content"*. Also, the comments section is not a place to ask a new, possibly unrelated question. If you have a question of your own, just start a new one and ask it.

Comment: @Kurt Pfeifle I mean any alternate solution/tool that can give better results. Also could you please suggest what command with options should we use to get optimal result to extract text from [Sample 1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j6puqwubuj8qxf4/FEATURE_TOP.pdf?dl=0) and [Sample 2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uo4zhou4571khka/SNARFS_AUSTIN.pdf?dl=0)

Comment: @AmitPatel: As I said -- please ask a new question!